# Simulating dummy data in mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm using a rails seed file, and it's generating users with attributes set to random values.

Simply creating a thousand users or so takes a good minute. Say I want to create 10,000 or 100,000. This would take a whole night to populate.

Is there a good way to doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting 10k entries will hardly take few seconds.
You can try inserting using the mongo shell. Following is a small code that you can modify according to your requirement.

```
generate_random_load(50, 'test3', ['_id','user'], 4)

Mongo > db.test3.find()
{ "_id" : "uNOK", "user" : "RlZS" }
{ "_id" : "tWHy", "user" : "xzGl" }
{ "_id" : "XUwH", "user" : "vySE" }
{ "_id" : "T8k0", "user" : "JMM2" }
{ "_id" : "H6R4", "user" : "HdZF" }
.....

function generate_random_load(count, collection_name, array_keys, key_size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var document = {};
        for (var j in array_keys) {
            document[array_keys[j]] = random_string(key_size);
        }
        getDB("test").getCollection(collection_name).insert(document);
    }
}

function random_string(len, charSet) {
    charSet = charSet ||
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var randomString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var randomPoz = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length);
        randomString += charSet.substring(randomPoz, randomPoz + 1);
    }
    return randomString;
}

function getDB(db_name) {
    return db.getMongo().getDB(db_name);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the nice answer. any idea why rails might take so long?

Comment: You can do few things to determines where the operation is going slow. Insert only 10-20 documents and:

1) Log all the response time per insert from your app.
2) Enable the database profiler, db.setProfilingLevel(2), and check, for the same inserts, how much time mongod took and compare with the above time.


This will tell you, if the application is taking time or mongod is taking time for insertion.


Can you also, post the client configuration when it connects to the database. I just want to see if you have enabled 'fsync' or 'j' parameter, which will make the insert to be very slow.